# Visual Studio Express 2015 - Windows Service

Tags: windows, service, visual-studio-2015

Fellow Stackers,

Can someone advise if it is possible to Create a Windows Service using VS Express 2015. I have tried searching for the template as you do with Visual Studio but no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't see if under Visual C# -> Windows -> Classic Desktop, you may not have all the right templates installed.  If I remember correctly I had to Install something related Windows Universal before I could see it (under Visual C# -> Windows somewhere).

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a template for a service in the VS community 2015 under VB > Windows > Classic Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use any version of VS Express to create windows services.  They are only for each indicated platform (Windows, Web, Desktop).

Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition is also free and it has much larger feature set including the ability to use extensions.  However, there also is no template to create Windows Services in the Community edition.

VS 2015 Professional is the 'lowest' edition that supports the use of the Windows Service template.